# Ralbag - "the reason for smart people often becoming heretical is because they are not smart enough" - source?

Tags: sources-mekorot, heresy, ralbag

Rav Paltiel quotes the Ralbag to the effect of the title, and adds his own explanation that there are many people who are smart enough to "understand the question, but not the answer".

Does anyone know what Ralbag this is and provide the source?

<sup>Note: it is reminiscent of the introduction to Chovot Halevavot, who said he wrote it for such a middle group of people who are smart enough to hear the deep questions of life, but they stand a very low chance of getting the right answer on their own.</sup>

Comment: Where does R. Paltiel quote the Ralbag?

Comment: @Deuteronomy I saw it in a short clip that doesn't say any more than I've brought here nor points to where it is originally from I am afraid :) the exact 'quote' from the Ralbag is "there are too many people who aren't smart enough"

Comment: Reminds me of what my Rosh Kollel said to me when I asked him, Why do Orthodox scientists and gedolei Torah gives very different answers to questions of science and Torah? Is that because the talmidei chachamim don't know enough science? He said, No! It's because they don't know enough Torah.

Comment: It would be helpful if you linked to Yossie's video link where you heard this.